# Code signing a static library for iOS

Tags: ios, static-libraries, code-signing

I have been looking into code signing in iOS, but there are still some things unclear to me. We have built a static library and we want to be able to ship it to customers soon. However, we need to be sure we're following the right code signing procedure to avoid any complaints from our customers.

The questions that I have are the following:

1. Is code signing a must in the case of a static library? or is it optional in our case?
2. Ideally, who should be code signing the library? Should it be us, or should it be the customer? If we're the ones who should do it, could it be done with any developers identity?
3. At some point we expect our client to update their app on the app store with our library. Is there a chance code signing the library can cause them problems? (if we're the ones code signing it)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to sign a static library. The code from the library will be embedded into the application which then will be signed by your customer. Your code will be covered by that signature as well. From the perspective of the finished app there is no difference of wether your code was added from a static library or if your source code was added to the project.